# authentification provider linux like ActiveDirectory

Tags: linux, active-directory

I'm looking for some analog of ActiveDirectory for Linux operating systems.
Is there any one?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130327/linux-based-solution-for-domain-management

Answer (score 0):

Search for "LDAP" and "Kerberos".